# Workflow not triggered

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow

We have a Workflow on a list in SharePoint 2013. When a user creates an item, the workflow is supposed to trigger and update the item with a reference code based on the users name and date. It then goes off and does other stuff.

However, this is intermittently failing to trigger the first step so the list items site there in an incomplete state. Can't find any rhyme or reason for why it triggers sometimes but not others.

Checked permissions of users creating items that don't trigger the workflow and they look good. 
Checked the logs and event viewer and can't see anything in there to suggest any issues. Checked timer services too.

Hoping someone out there might have an idea. All help greatly appreciated.

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Is this workflow using the 2013 style or 2010 style? If 2013, I've seen that people who have permissions because they are in an AD group, either directly or having the AD group inside of a SharePoint permission group, won't actually have enough permission to get through the Workflow Manager - it's not 'smart' enough to dig into the AD group. They have to be in a permission group themselves.  Long shot but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Thanks Robin, I'll take a look into this but the issue is intermittent so Permissions seem unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

What’s the steps you set in the workflow? Make sure the steps configured correctly.

Clear the SharePoint Designer cache and republish this workflow, check if the issue exists.

[How to Clear Your SharePoint Designer 2010/2013 Cache](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33469.how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache.aspx)

You can add “Log to History list” action behind each action in the workflow, then check the error message in the History list.

Comment: Fiona - Thanks for the suggestion of the 'Log to History' - I'll try this and see what gets revealed.